# Are product / coproduct projections / inclusions 'semistrict'?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, exact-categories

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category with zero object, kernels, and cokernels.  Then, a morphism $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ in $\mathbf{C}$ is *semistrict* iff the canonical map $\operatorname{Coker}(\ker (f))\rightarrow \operatorname{Ker}(\operatorname{coker}(f))$ is both a pseudomonomorphism and a pseudoepimorphism (a *pseudobimorphism*).  (The term derives from the fact that a preabelian category is said to be (by [some](https://www.math.uni-trier.de/abteilung/analysis/HomAlg.pdf)---the terminology is [not standard](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category)) *semiabelian* iff this canonical map is always a bimorphism (and of course *abelian* iff this canonical map is always an isomorphism), and the fact that a morphism is said to be *strict* iff this canonical map is an isomorphism.)

Question:

> Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a finitely-complete finitely-cocomplete category with zero object and let $A_1,A_2\in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathbf{C})$.  Is it necessarily the case that the projections $\pi _k\colon A_1\times A_2\rightarrow A_k$ and the inclusions $\iota _k\colon A_k\rightarrow A_1\sqcup A_2$ are semistrict?

Disclaimer:  I first asked this question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735513/are-product-coproduct-projections-inclusions-semistrict), and after over a week with no answer, I decided to ask here as well.  For what it's worth, while I haven't thought about the question too much since I first asked it, my feeling is that the statement is probably false, simply because (i) my guess is that, were such a statement to be true, its proof would be relatively elementary, and (ii) I spent a couple of days trying all the elementary tricks I could think of (though perhaps I was just being dense . . .).

Comment: What are pseudomonomorphisms and pseudoepimorphisms?

Comment: $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ is pseudomonic iff $0\rightarrow A$ is a kernel of $f$ (and dually for pseudoepis).

Comment: Have you checked some simple examples, like the category of pointed sets?

Comment: @MikeShulman I recall checking both pointed-sets and pointed-spaces.  I didn't write-up a proof that I can go back and look at to double-check, but if memory serves I did verify that projections and inclusions indeed are semistrict in these categories,

Comment: In fact, the specific example of $\mathbb{R}\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ (base-points are $0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $1\in S^1=U(1)$) played an (indirect) part in motivating the question.  In this example, the kernel is $\mathbb{R}\times \{ 1\}$, and the cokernel of $\mathbb{R}\times \{ 1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times S^1$ is a cylinder with the 'vertical' line $\mathbb{R}\times \{ 1\}$ identified to a point.  The canonical map from this to $S^1$ is surjective (and so a pseudoepi) and has kernel a point.  I think this behavior is pretty generic for projections in pointed-sets.

Comment: Presumably this is a standard result for Abelian categories, so you should examine the textbook proof to see if it generalises.  It seems unlikely to me, because, in the absence of subtraction, the kernel of $f$ should be $\{(x,y)|f(x)=f(y)\}$ not just $\{x|f(x)=0\}$ as presumably you're using. [Zurab Janelidze](http://zurab.academy/) did some work on generalising Abelian categories that might be relevant.

Comment: In an abelian category, a morphism is a pushout-stable-normal monomorphism iff it is psrudomonic (and dually). In particular, projections and inclusions are normal, and so the canonical map in question is an isomorphism. This fails completely in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is, I claim, a counterexample.  Consider the category $\mathrm{Cat}_*$ of pointed categories, i.e. the coslice category $1/\mathrm{Cat}$.  Let $A$ be the walking involution, i.e. it has one object $a$ with one nonidentity morphism $e:a\to a$ such that $e e = 1_a$.  Let $B$ be the discrete category on two objects $b,c$, with say $b$ as the basepoint.  Then $A\times B$ is just two copies of $A$; consider its projection to $A$.  This is surjective, so its cokernel is $1$, and then of course the kernel of the cokernel is $A$.

The kernel of a map in $\mathrm{Cat}_*$ is the non-full subcategory of its domain consisting of those objects that map to the basepoint and those morphisms that map to the identity of the basepoint.  Thus, the kernel of $\pi:A\times B\to A$ is just $B$.  Now the cokernel of this kernel $B\to A\times B$ is the quotient of $A\times B$ obtained by identifying its two objects --- but not doing anything to its morphisms.  Thus, it has one object, say $d$, and *two* endomorphisms $e_1,e_2:d\to d$ with $e_1 e_1 = 1_d$ and $e_2 e_2 = 1_d$, but no relation between them.  In particular, $e_1 e_2$ is not the identity, but it does map to the identity in $A$.  Hence, the kernel of the induced map $\mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{ker}(\pi)) \to A = \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{coker}(\pi))$ is nontrivial, so that map is not pseudomonic in your sense, and so $\pi$ is not semistrict.